# Models in unity from Blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

i'm making a tank based game and when i made a model of the tank in blender and imported it to unity. When I placed a camera inside the wall was completely transparent from the inside but not the outside.
Is there any simple fix to this problem?

Comment: The problem you have is called backface culling, you can disable with a [shader](https://twitter.com/HarryAlisavakis/status/1067357331627933696?s=20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In blender you have to make sure your normals are facing outward. If you are using planes imported from Unity they will only show up on one side, its better to use cubes if you want them to be visible for both sides. If you are using a plane you can create a custom 'CULL OFF' shader so that backface culling will disable on its material and will show on both sides.